# How to get engagement value or persona

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

**Scenario**

I am working on this requirement - A visitor on the website will be assigned points for their activities on the website like views, likes, shares etc. Based on those points, they will be awarded levels - level1, level2, etc., which will be shown on page when they are logged in.

I'm working on the xDB features for the first time and have a few questions listed below.

1. The points assigned to a `Goal`/`Page Event` combine & accumulate as `Engagement Value` for a user. Is this correct?
2. When reading data from MongoDB, can we get the `Engagement Value` of logged in user from just one field, or do we need to read each `Goal`/`Page Event` by ID, and get their values.
3. There is something called `Persona` which has Min. & Max. points. Are these mapped to the `Engagement Value`. Say, there is a `Persona` called `Business man` with Min. points as 0 and Max. points as 10, and if a user's `Engagement Value` >=10, will this persona be automatically associated with that user.

If I create personas for each such level by setting the respective points, will the engagement value of the user be auto mapped to the persona. Then I can try to get the persona name and display.

Am I going the right way. If not, please advise how to proceed.

Using sc 8.0 u4 with MongoDB 3.4.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The points assigned to a Goal/Page Event combine & accumulate as
>   Engagement Value for a user. Is this correct?

Yes, you are correct. You assign engagement value points to score specific contact actions and behaviors, such as achieving a goal or triggering a page event. [[Engagement Value]](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/personalization/insession_personalization/engagement_value_points).

> When reading data from MongoDB, can we get the Engagement Value of
>   logged in user from just one field, or do we need to read each
>   Goal/Page Event by ID, and get their values.

You can get the Engagement Value for each visitor from the MongoDB Contacts Collections. You need to perform a query to the Contact Collection to retrieve the data from the field `value`.

[image]

> There is something called Persona which has Min. & Max. points. Are
>   these mapped to the Engagement Value. Say, there is a Persona called
>   Business man with Min. points as 0 and Max. points as 10, and if a
>   user's Engagement Value >=10, will this persona be automatically
>   associated with that user.

Personas are the same as Profile. Based on your example, the Min and Max is used to see in which pattern the visitor is in. Sitecore makes use of the different Interactions of the visitor to know in which pattern the user is. So, for example, if a visitor has visited most pages which was tag with the Profile Card Business man, he will be added to the pattern. The value of Min Max is for Sitecore to be able to perform the **Euclidean distance** to know which pattern the visitor is matched and does not depend on the Engagement Value.

> If I create personas for each such level by setting the respective
>   points, will the engagement value of the user be auto mapped to the
>   persona. Then I can try to get the persona name and display.

Sitecore will automatically set the visitor to a Persona based on the interaction. If the visitor is, for example, visiting pages that are tag with **Level 1**, the user pattern will be Level 1. But this will keep on changing based on the pages being visited.

For your case, I think, it will be better to make use of Goals and Outcome to know on which Level the user is. Because the Pattern and Profile Cards will change. A user may be in Level 4 but if he browses pages which were tag with Level 1, Sitecore will change the pattern of the user to Level 1.

So, by making use of Goals and Outcome, you can see if the User trigger a certain goal, you assigned it to a Level.

Comment: (1) Sitecore will use the min/max points in a profile key and this is not for the author/developer to use. Is that right. (2) Could you please give any pointers about tagging and getting engagement value from code. I couldn't find anything online and the only one found in SSE was incomplete. Thank you.